# Calculate sum of column using group by in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with this structure :

```
public class Factor
    {
        public DateTime? date { set; get; }
        public string InnovoiceId { set; get; }
        public string explain { set; get; }
        public string tax { set; get; }
        public string transport { set; get; }
        public Int64? bedehkar { set; get; }
        public Int64? bestankar { set; get; }
        public Int64? mande { set; get; }
    }

        List<Factor> factors = new List<Factor>();
```

I created a query that groups the records based on **InnovoiceId** .And calculate the sum of **Tax** and sum of **transport** and **bedehkar** and **bestankar** and **mande**.

My query is:

```
  List<Factor> factorSortList =
           factors.OrderBy(o => o.date)
                  .ToList()
                  .GroupBy(i => i.InnovoiceId)
                  .Select(g => new { tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)), transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)), bedehkar = g.Sum(i => i.bedehkar), bestankar = g.Sum(i => i.bestankar), mande = g.Sum(i => i.mande) });
```

But i got this  error:

```
   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<samtaApplication.BuLayer.Payment.ReportPayment.Factor>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: I don't want to use **var** .i need to return Factor type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous type

```
.Select(g => new { ... });
```

and pretending it's a `Factor`

```
List<Factor> factorSortList = ...
```

You'll need to use `var` since it's an anonymous type or create a different type in that select statement.

The following is one way to resolve this as well as the fact that 2 of your `Sum` variables are `string` and not numeric (assuming `int`, but what you may desire here instead is `double`.

```
var factorSortList =
       factors.OrderBy(o => o.date)
              .ToList()
              .GroupBy(i => i.InnovoiceId)
              .Select(g => new { tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)), transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)), bedehkar = g.Sum(i => i.bedehkar), bestankar = g.Sum(i => i.bestankar), mande = g.Sum(i => i.mande) });
```

Or if your aggregated type here is meant to be `Factor`...

```
              .Select(g => new Factor() { tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)).ToString(), transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)).ToString(), bedehkar = g.Sum(i => i.bedehkar), bestankar = g.Sum(i => i.bestankar), mande = g.Sum(i => i.mande) }).ToList();
```

Comment: i changed to it :  List<Factor> factorSortList =
            factors.OrderBy(o => o.date)
                   .ToList()
                   .GroupBy(i => i.InnovoiceId)
                   .Select(g => new Factor()
                   {
                       tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)).ToString(),
                       transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)).ToString(),
                       bedehkar = g.Sum(i => i.bedehkar),
                       bestankar = g.Sum(i => i.bestankar),
                       mande = g.Sum(i => i.mande)
                   });

Comment: I don't want to use var .i need to return Factor type

Comment: @user3216600 - use your code but add `.ToList()` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Change these statements:

```
tax = g.Sum(i => i.tax), transport = g.Sum(i => i.transport),
```

to:

```
tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)), transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)),
```

And you are creating an anonymous type in your Select statement but you are trying to assign it to a List, change it like this:

```
.Select(g => new Factory { .. });
```

But then your `Sum` functions will return int,and your property types are `string`.You should convert each of them, if you don't need a `List<Factory>` so much then just use implicit type definition with var:

```
var  factorSortList = ...
```

Here is the full statement if you want   `List<Factor>`

```
List<Factor> factorSortList =
       factors.OrderBy(o => o.date)
              .ToList()
              .GroupBy(i => i.InnovoiceId)
              .Select(g => new Factor () 
                      {
                            tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)).ToString(),
                            transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)).ToString(),
                            bedehkar = g.Sum(i => i.bedehkar),
                            bestankar = g.Sum(i => i.bestankar),
                            mande = g.Sum(i => i.mande)
                      });
```

Comment: The last error is fixed but the first one is remained

Comment: Changed to Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<samtaApplication.BuLayer.Payment.ReportPayment.Factor>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an anonymous type with your `Select` statement, which can't be implicitly converted to an instance of `Factor`. Try `Select`ing an new `Factor`, like this:

```
List<Factor> factorSortList =
           factors.OrderBy(o => o.date)
                  .ToList()
                  .GroupBy(i => i.InnovoiceId)
                  .Select(g => new Factor () 
                          {
                                tax = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.tax)),
                                transport = g.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.transport)),
                                bedehkar = g.Sum(i => i.bedehkar),
                                bestankar = g.Sum(i => i.bestankar),
                                mande = g.Sum(i => i.mande)
                          });
```

Although since `Factor.tax` and `Factor.transport` are `string`s, you'll want to add a `.ToString()` to the result of `.Sum` for those.